# bundle exec rake db:setup, Rake tasks not supported by 'username' adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, fedora

When I try to run `bundle exec rake db:setup` ,It gives me this error

and when I change the adapter to my username I got the same error

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
: CREATE DATABASE "freelance_camp_documents_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"freelance_camp_documents_development"}
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
: CREATE DATABASE "freelance_camp_documents_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-
```

I can't put the whole error here
and here is the `database.yml` code

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: freelance_camp_documents_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: freelance_camp_documents_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: freelance_camp_documents_production
  username: freelance_camp_documents
  password: <%= ENV['FREELANCE_CAMP_DOCUMENTS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: I hope you are running in `development` mode. You didn't specify any username in `database.yml` for this mode.

Comment: @31piy I noticed that from the database.yml file , but how to run dev mode. I just run the line `bundle exec rake db:setup' in the terminal and got this error , I'm not running the server yet.

Comment: It is not related to running the server. You need to specify the user which you want to use in your `database.yml` file, so that rails can setup that DB. You need to visit to your postgres setup for this.

Answer (score 0):

> PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database

The problem here is you don't have sufficient privileges to user `freelance_camp_documents` on Postgres.

I will suggest to change permissions for user `freelance_camp_documents` from postgres or just change username to `postgres`

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: freelance_camp_documents_production
  username: postgres
  password: <%= ENV['FREELANCE_CAMP_DOCUMENTS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

`postgres` user has permissions by default so you don't need to change anything

Comment: I changed the user name in database.yml and the same error :\